# Blazor Web Assembly Not Returning DB Rows Captured in Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a request from my Razor code to my controller and return my one row I know I have in my DB.

The Scoop - I make the GET call in my Razor -> It goes to GET in my controller, where I  KNOW it returns my one DB row. So everything looks fine on the back end. THEN I return that back to my frontend BUT the data from the GET to my controller is not there, instead it just contains the original data I put in the object.

This is a Blazor Web Assembly app so I have done all debugging in the browser for the front end stuff and VS for anything back end to see what is going on. BUT I can't figure out what the deal is here...

Whats going on here????

```html
/*Razror C#*/

private List<Items> items;

private int Id { get; set; } = 0;
private string Name { get; set; } = "";
private string Description { get; set; } = "";


protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

   items = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Items>>(APIServer);

   //value - 0
   int testID = items.ElementAt(0).Id;

   value - ""
   string testNAME = items.ElementAt(0).Name;

   value - ""
   string testDES = items.ElementAt(0).Description;

}
    
    
    
    
    ....
    
    
 /*Controller*/       
    
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetAsync()
{
   List<Item> currentIems= new List<Item>();
   currentItems = await _dbContext.Item.ToListAsync();


   //this DOES in fact return my 1 row I have in the DB
   return currentItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo , you could refer to:

*items.Razor*

```
@page "/Items"
@inject HttpClient Http

<div>
@if (items == null)
{
    <div>Loading...</div>
}
else
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@items.ElementAt(0).Id</td>
                <td>@items.ElementAt(0).Name</td>
                <td>@items.ElementAt(0).Description</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
</div>

@code {
  private List<Item> items;

  private class Item
  {
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
  }


  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    items = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Item>>("https://localhost:44370/api/test");
  }
}
```

*WebAPI controller*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public readonly WebAPIDbContext _dbContext;
    public TestController(WebAPIDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetAsync()
    {
        List<Item> currentItems = new List<Item>();
        currentItems = await _dbContext.Item.ToListAsync();


        //this DOES in fact return my 1 row I have in the DB
        return currentItems;
    }
}
```

*Add CORS middleware configuration to the WebAPI's Startup.Configure*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44356")
                  .AllowAnyMethod();
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

*Result*
[image]